# QGIS - Add a circle from 2 points is not creating a circle

Tags: qgis, editing, circle

I am trying to create a circle from two points when editing a layer. When I begin to add the 2 points it looks like a circle, but as soon as I right click to add the feature it changes shape as shown in the screen shot. Why is it doing this?

I am using 'toggle editing' to edit a layer and then the 'add circle from 2 points' tool.

[image]

Comment: Because it gets (de-)projected; a circle on a planar projection is not equal to a circle on the spheroid, and *vice versa*.

Comment: I guess we need some more details on this. For starters, I don't see any points, and you didn't mention the tools your using.

Comment: @geozelot Thanks, I am very new to QGIS, can I reproject to maintain the circle shape? Or do I just have to live with the misshaped circle?

Comment: @Erik I have amended the post to include some more detail. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is [a bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38493) that is currently open. The problem seems to occur if your layer uses a geographic coordinate system (such as EPSG:4326) while your project uses a projected coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks @Jake, I re-projected the layer to EPSG:3857 (same as the project) and that fixed the problem, I can now create circular layer features.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful as well? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398543/88814

Comment: A "circular" circle in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) has no meaning whatsoever. The projection is incapable of representing distances correctly, so if it looks like a circle, then you can be sure the figure doesn't represent one.