# Basemap and shapefile CRS issues

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, time-series

I am trying to overlay a timeseries shapefile over a geographic basemap, but the coordinate systems are not the same. I have set the project CRS to EPSG:4326, hence making the basemap in lat/long.

[image: The area of interest, Myanmar, in CRS EPSG:4326]

However, the shapefile when imported into the project has native CRS in easting/northing (UTM) it seems.

[image: Myanmar timeseries, in easting/northing]

I am unsure of how to transform between these two so that the timeseries shapefile is overlayed on the base map.

Comment: QGIS knows how to relate different CRS to each other. This is know as `on the fly reporjection`. Have you tried adding the shape on top of the base map? If so, what happens?

Comment: Hi friend. The above images are the results of me adding the shp layer on top of the base map.

Comment: Did you change layer CRS? Be sure **not** to change (set) the layer CRS manually. What you can change manually is the project CRS (as you did). See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: @Babel, yes, I unfortunately still get (even after reprojection) my .shp in UTM.

Comment: Open a new QGIS project, load a basemap. Then load your shapefile without changing anything. If its not in the correct place, there is an error in the file. Can you share it?

Comment: Sure thing, thank you for your help. These files should enable you to view the timeseries points: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i4KinwQ7TOdrPacVUlAZfOLJpSArJXIn?usp=sharing @Babel.

Comment: Your layer in in PESG:4326 - I guess you or someone else did what I mentioned above (changed layer CRS) and saved it as such. So you must find out the initial CRS: do you still have the initial (unchanged) file at hand? Or do you know the area of the world the points should be located (e.g. which UTM zone - if an UTM-based CRS was used)?

Comment: If you change (this time, indeed!) the CRS of your layer to e.g. `EPSG:32247`, your points will be placed in northern Myanmar - see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HW0A.png

Comment: @Babel you are a legend...thank you!!

Comment: This is a variant of the most-asked question on this site, the QGIS canonical duiplicate of which is  [Layer disappears when changing from CRS in degrees to CRS in meters in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348521/layer-disappears-when-changing-from-crs-in-degrees-to-crs-in-meters-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by @Babel.

"If you change (this time, indeed!) the CRS of your layer to e.g. EPSG:32247, your points will be placed in northern Myanmar - see: i.stack.imgur.com/6HW0A.png"

Comment: Be aware to really find the correct CRS: aprart from `EPSG:32247`, there are other (similar) CRS for that region - so make sure to find the correct one.

Comment: Hi Babel, 

How do you find the other CRS for a region? I am now looking within Kyrgyzstan. Thanks!