# Buffering like set to lat/lon degrees but layer is set to UTM reprojection - EPSG: 32611

Tags: coordinate-system, buffer, epsg

I have two line and point features to buffer. I have reprojected to UTM EPSG: 32611 for both.

Please, see screen capture showing the direct GeoPackage layer properties and not from the Layers window.

I have small points like these but they get enlarged as if I had set the projection to a lat/lon type.

[image: see screen capture showing the GeoPackage layer properties]
[image: I have small points like these but they get enlarged as if I had set the projection to a lat/lon type]

[image: This is the result of the buffer as if I set it to 3 degrees across the whole planet! But I am using a UTM with meters... what is wrong?]

This is the result of the buffer as if I set it to 3 degrees across the whole planet! But I am using a UTM with meters... what is wrong?

I have reprojected the EPSG beyond the map project and on the actual layer into a new GeoPackage... Any ideas for a fix?

I am using QGIS 3.22.1 the latest for 2021.

I originally digitized a map overlay to QMS Google Satellite coordinates. Other layers I added were on the fly projected to this location with ease. I decided to start reprojecting everything to the desired EPSG: 32611 system and am still having trouble. I have read the manual and tried other posts.

This is the settings -> options configuration for the CRS in this photo.
[image: Settings]

Comment: Don't **SET** a projection. Instead **reproject** your data. Check the answers to this question for more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348521/layer-disappears-when-changing-from-crs-in-degrees-to-crs-in-meters-in-qgis

Comment: I have tried "reproject" from the processing toolbox and tried buffering those too. They keep returning the larger degree points. I have also exported -> save feature... None of this is working as usual.

Comment: But before doing so, you did set it back to its original crs? If not the reprojection wont work.

Comment: I am going to add an image to my first post... I did arrange the "Settings" configuration if that is what you mean.

Comment: I strongly recommend to choose "Leave as an unknown CRS (take no action)" or "Promt for CRS" within "CRS for layers". Otherwise you can be trapped in reprojection issues repeatedly without taking notice of it. For now anyway: set that setting, remove the layer from your project, add it back and see which crs is **set**. If none is set, you have to guess. The first to try would be to **set** it to EPSG:4326. If then everything is in the right place you can reproject it to UTM.

Comment: It appears I assigned the CRS also to the project EPSG: 32611. And yes, some of the layers are set and projected at EPSG:4326. 

From reproject tool, I see only the target CRS to add and the algorithm appears to assume the current CRS (the original you mean?).

Comment: I am working on all the layers to share the EPSG reproject at EPSG 32611.

Comment: I removed and checked all the layers... they are all showing my reprojection or exported projection EPSG:32611 but it seems to be of no use. One layer of streams is showing up in a nearby vicinity but not near the rest of the layers. I am wondering if I need to start over or reinstall QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to restart the exercise, and it turns out that using the QMS Google satellite and the digitizing of a layer threw of my projections on the fly. It turned into a disaster, so I had to restart the editing of points and very carefully make sure the reprojections were not just assigned but setup properly in matching EPSG:3857. This one works because it uses meters as units.

I found setting a relative EPSG typically messes up the whole process and that it is better to export or reproject immediately. I also did reprojection directly from the on the fly layer if possible. I have had "." file errors using these algorithms before where I had to go to the source layer, but the reprojection did always work this way for some reason, likely due to its mismatch with QMS Google.

Now starting with it matching QMS Google satellite everything works.