# Imported layer misaligns with OSM using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, alignment, prj

I downloaded a layer from a public website and I want to align the layer with OpenStreetMap. To do so I set the project's and OSM's CRS to the CRS of the layer. However, it appeared far from its expected place.

Moreover, the layer came with a brief pdf that stated it's a *Krasovsky_1940_Equidistant_Conic* projection. I tried already to apply the *EPSG:4024 - Unknown datum based upon the Krassowsky 1940 ellipsoid* but there was no improvement.

I tried other different combinations of CRS but so far nothing worked out... [image: Result of setting Project CRS and OSM CRS to layer CRS (ETRS89-LAEA5220)]

The ".prj" file of the layer has the following code:

```
GEOGCS["ETRS89",
DATUM["<custom>",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",5071000.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",3210000.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",20.0],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",52.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** "set" the coordinate reference of a layer that has one.  Doing so effectively lies to the software, and it's gullible enough to believe you, and that will trash your map. Instead, you need to **project**, or **transform** or **change** it (the terms are slightly different across platforms) to a new coordinate reference. Repairing this can be as simple as setting it back to what it was, or reacquiring it as necessary, then transforming it correctly.

Comment: Since this is another version of the most common Question on this site, I've voted to close it with the canonical QGIS flavor [as per the meta guideline](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/what-is-the-canonical-question-to-close-layers-with-the-same-crs-not-overlappin) -- [Layer disappears when changing from CRS in degrees to CRS in meters in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348521/layer-disappears-when-changing-from-crs-in-degrees-to-crs-in-meters-in-qgis)