# Projection issue QGIS3.2

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I georeferenced all my layers and set it to NAD83 CRSUTM 17N for the whole project, as well as individual layers. Checked and re-tried everything but the raster is still ending up in water somewhere and not in Ontario region as I would like it to be. Anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the layers?

Comment: Just because you assert that the coordinates are in a certain projection doesn't make it so. You should *almost never* define the projection of your data sources. If you want to reproject a dataset, you need to project it, not define it to the wrong value. This is the most frequent question here, with the canonical Q&A for QGIS [Layer disappears when changing from CRS in degrees to CRS in meters in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348521/layer-disappears-when-changing-from-crs-in-degrees-to-crs-in-meters-in-qgis)